# Why should the wheel be round?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

> Is there a theoretical argument which shows that among all the possible shapes, the best choice for a wheel is to be circular?

Intuitively, it makes quite a lot of sense to me, but I'd be interested to see a kind of characterization of the circle as the most efficient wheel possible. Where, of course, "most efficient" should be defined in a suitable manner (and I guess this the hear of my question).

There is this [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/94107/rigid-bodies-the-wheel) which states that "the wheel has a unique property: at every moment of motion, the touching point between the wheel and the ground is not in movement and therefore no work is done by the friction force." However, I'm having a hard time to understand why there should be more friction if a car has squared wheels. Indeed, I can fairly imagine that squared wheel are quite inefficient, but this is because you have to lift the car up to pass the corners, and not because of the friction (I might be wrong though).

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/285767/25301

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do circular wheels maximize mechanical efficiency?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/285767/)

Comment: @KyleKanos Thanks, this is quite precisely what I wanted to know.

Comment: @Surb do accept the answer if it helps

Answer (score 3):

For a wheel, it undergoes sliding and rolling friction as it moves.  Do note that sliding and rolling friction act in opposite directions, so they cancel out.  In a wheel both of the frictions are roughly equal, so the wheel experiences little or no friction.  However, a square wheel has a relatively large sliding friction due to its large faces, making the friction greater than a circular wheel.